# Links colours are not distinctive enough

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

In the main site, the links are slightly blueish: rgb(43, 109, 151), I find them difficult to distinguish from the body text color: rgb(51, 51, 51).

Perhaps it's my monitor, or my eyes, but I don't feel that way with other SE sites.

I suggest increasing the saturation.

Update: Here's an screenshot (Chrome on Win7). If find the links to "zgv" and "mplayer", for example, difficult to detect. (They are unvisited - "SDL" is visited).

[image]

Comment: Then its also my monitor and/or my eyes. I set `a { text-decoration: underline !important; }` CSS for them using Stylish. As Jukka Korpela wrote: “[Links Want To Be Links](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/links.html)”.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. The only way I can tell if it's a link is staring intently at it or running my mouse over to see if it's clickable.

Comment: I regularly miss links that are not clearly advertised as links, in part because my eyes are not as good as they used to be. I'd love to have links underlined.

Answer (score 2):

***Edit:***

Had not visited U&L on Windows, but seeing your update with picture and also testing on XP and 7 I see the problem. As Windows fonts in general is much thinner the effect is unfortunate.

---

Haven't noticed a problem with it here. If for anything the difference between [unvisited](http://asdf.nonexistent) and [visited](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com) could be better, but hasn't been a problem I've given much thought (as in I manage to distinguish between them without much conscious thought).

As a test you could go trough [this guide](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/) `<-- That is a link ;-)`. Go full-screen by (typically `F11`) and click trough the images at top. Each test has text that describes what you should see, and in some cases how to view them as well as how to correct some of the cases.

---

Doubtful this will show differently as picture, but here we go:

- Unvisited:  `rgb(21, 86, 128)`
- Visited:`rgb(43, 109, 151)`
- Text: `rgb(51, 51, 51)`

Mesh:

```
#155680     #2b6d97     #333
```

[image: colors for anchors and text]
[image: colors for anchors and text mesh]

Mozilla Firefox – Linux (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, openSUSE, LinuxMint):

[image: Firefox Linux sample anchors]